# How to get entire line that contains given string using findstr in batch script?

Tags: batch-file, svn, tortoisesvn, findstr

I need to get the line that contains the keyword `ProductVersion` from one of my *svn* repository `csproj` files. I have tried below code, but it is not working as expected.

The batch file is:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem https://testur/test.csproj
for %%t in (%*) do (
    rem echo url: %%t
    for /f "tokens=1" %%c in ('svn cat %%t ^| findstr /i ProductVersion') do (
        echo output: %%c
    )
)
```

`csproj` file content:

```
<VisualStudioProject>
    <CSHARP
        ProjectType = "Local"
        ProductVersion = "7.10.3077"
        Schemaversion = "2.0"
```

Here the url is passed as command line argument to the batch file. The `ProductVersion` line in `csproj` file also contains `=` and some spaces. `svn cat %%t` would return me the content of file `test.csproj`. I am applying `findstr` on the received file content. When I tried with above code it returns only `ProductVersion` without the remaining string `"7.0.3077"` as output.

How to get the `ProductVerion` value `7.0.3077` or the entire line?

Comment: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `for /?` and read the output help, especially the paragraphs about usage of `for /F`. `"tokens=1"` results in assigning to specified loop variable `c` just the first space/tab delimited string of each line if the first substring does not start with `;` being the default end of line character. Either use `"delims="` to disable line splitting by definition of an empty list of delimiters or in case of lines can start with `;` the expression `delims^=^ eol^=` without `"` to additionally define no end of line character.

Comment: But you want just the product version value and so the command line `for /F "tokens=2 delims== " %%I in ('svn.exe cat %%t ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /C:ProductVersion') do echo Product version is: %%~I` is the really needed line. The second command line of the batch file should be replaced to `setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion` as delayed variable expansion is not needed for the posted code and a URL can contain exclamation marks which should be interpreted as literal characters and not as beginning/end of a delayed expanded variable reference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! @Mofi :) this is perfect fix for my problem.

Comment: `for /f "tokens=1,2delims== " %%c in ('svn cat %%t') do if "%%c"=="ProductVersion" echo %%~c` may be perfecter.

Comment: @Magoo: yes, for very short files. For bigger files, the `findstr` method is a lot faster (only process the relevant line(s) with the loop instead of each and every line)